Solutions of the functional equation $f(x) = f(x/2) + 1$
Is there a nice characterization of all functions $f : (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = f(x/2) + 1$?
Obviously, there are many solutions involving the base-2 logarithm. For example, any $x \mapsto 1 + g(\log_2 x)$ where $g$ is a real function such that $g(0) = 0$ and $g(x - 1) = g(x) - 1$. (Notably, $g$ can be the identity, floor, ceiling, or anything in between).
The only parts of its domain that $f$ is constrained on are the sets $M(a) = \{ a2^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ where $a$ is a positive real. You can use this to construct stranger solutions, such as
$$
x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
1000(1 + \log_2(3x)) & \text{if } \log_2(3x) \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
1 + \log_2(x) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
My best hypothesis is that $f$ is a union of functions $f_a : M(a) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_a(x) = c_a(1 + g_a(\log_2(x/a)))$ for some $c_a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g_a$ like $g$ as described earlier, but I don't really know how to prove this and I suspect that even wilder solutions exist. Does anyone have any suggestions?

If you consider the functional equation $g(t+a)-g(t)=1$ then the simplest solution is $g_0(t)=t/a$ and $p(t)=g(t)-g_0(t)$ is an ARBITRARY periodic function of period $a.$ Now apply this to $g(t)=f(e^t/2)$ and $a=\log 2$ for getting ALL the solutions.

Thanks! Took a bit of work, but I was able to use this to show that the set of solutions is exactly the set of functions $f : (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = p(a \log_2 x) + \log_2 x + 1$ for all $x \in (0, +\infty)$, where $p : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is any periodic function whose period is $a$.
If I may ask, is there a particular strategy you used to figure this out? Just wondering in case I encounter this sort of problem again.

yes: two techniques. First replace the group of  positive numbers (for  multiplication) by the more familiar group of real numbers (for addition) for landing on something more familiar. Second: imitate the linear differential equations of order one by studying the homogeneous part and looking for a particular solution for the non homogeous equation.
